# How to extract the hidden values of the form and insert them to a database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Hellow guys? Ineed to fetch the hidden values of this form and insert them to a database. Can someone help me please? This is the code:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']"  value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Is `$cart_items` a dynamic variable?

Comment: Without the name of the element, you can't fetch it. No idea what $cart_items stores.

Comment: `$cart_items` sounds like an array name, not something that should be an array key!

Comment: Am starting learning and am not that expert in coding..so i will real appreciate if you give me something to start up with..thank you

Comment: @maro You need to show more code, because it is very hard for use to see what your trying to do with just 4 lines

Answer (score 1):

Hidden values are like anykind of input. Really.

```
<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']"  value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';

echo '<input type="hidden" name="cart_items" value="'.$cart_items.'"/>';
?>
```

Then after the post, you can use $_POST['cart_items'] to get back the $cart_items.

And echo the datas like this:

```
<?php
$cart_items = $_POST['cart_items'];

echo "Item name:".$_POST['item_name[".$cart_items."]'];

?>
```

And so on..

But I don't understand why you use name like item_name[variable].
It's easier and more valide to use item_name_$variable

Comment: They may have multiple form elements with the same name, they as only shown a small piece of code and you have to assume there is lots more.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a form out of this first. Then based on the HTTP method of the form, you would extract the values with $_POST['element_name'] or $_GET['element_name'] and send those values to the database.